# Writing and Reading lists to TFRecord example

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I want to write a list of integers (or any multidimensional numpy matrix) to one TFRecords example. For both a single value or a list of multiple values I can creates the TFRecord file without error. I know also how to read the single value back from TFRecord file as shown in the below code sample I compiled from various sources.

```
# Making an example TFRecord

my_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'my_ints': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[5]))
}))

my_example_str = my_example.SerializeToString()
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('my_example.tfrecords') as writer:
    writer.write(my_example_str)

# Reading it back via a Dataset

featuresDict = {'my_ints': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)}

def parse_tfrecord(example):
    features = tf.parse_single_example(example, featuresDict)
    return features

Dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('my_example.tfrecords')
Dataset = Dataset.map(parse_tfrecord)
iterator = Dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(iterator.get_next()))
```

But how can I read back a list of values (e.g. [5,6]) from one example? The `featuresDict` defines the feature to be of type int64, and it fails when I have multiple values in it and I get below error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Key: my_ints.  Can't parse serialized Example.
```

Comment: A more flexible way is to use `tf.io.serialize_tensor` and `tf.io.parse_tensor`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60283571/6393479

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using tf.train.SequenceExample. I've edited your code to return both 1D and 2D data. First, you create a list of features which you place in a tf.train.FeatureList. We convert our 2D data to bytes.

```
vals = [5, 5]
vals_2d = [np.zeros((5,5), dtype=np.uint8), np.ones((5,5), dtype=np.uint8)]

features = [tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[val])) for val in vals]
features_2d = [tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[val.tostring()])) for val in vals_2d]
featureList = tf.train.FeatureList(feature=features)
featureList_2d = tf.train.FeatureList(feature=features_2d)
```

In order to get the correct shape of our 2D feature we need to provide context (non-sequential data), this is done with a context dictionary.

```
context_dict = {'height': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[vals_2d[0].shape[0]])), 
            'width': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[vals_2d[0].shape[1]])),
           'length': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[len(vals_2d)]))}
```

Then you place each FeatureList in a tf.train.FeatureLists dictionary. Finally, this is placed in a tf.train.SequenceExample along with the context dictionary

```
my_example = tf.train.SequenceExample(feature_lists=tf.train.FeatureLists(feature_list={'1D':featureList,
                                                                                   '2D': featureList_2d}),
                                 context = tf.train.Features(feature=context_dict))
my_example_str = my_example.SerializeToString()
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('my_example.tfrecords') as writer:
    writer.write(my_example_str)
```

To read it back into tensorflow you need to use tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature for the sequential data and tf.FixedLenFeature for the context data. We convert the bytes back to integers and we parse the context data in order to restore the correct shape.

```
# Reading it back via a Dataset
featuresDict = {'1D': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
           '2D': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], dtype=tf.string)}
contextDict = {'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
          'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
          'length':tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64)}

def parse_tfrecord(example):
    context, features = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(
                            example, 
                            sequence_features=featuresDict,                                                   
                            context_features=contextDict
                        )

    height = context['height']
    width = context['width']
    seq_length = context['length']
    vals = features['1D']
    vals_2d = tf.decode_raw(features['2D'], tf.uint8)
    vals_2d = tf.reshape(vals_2d, [seq_length, height, width])
    return vals, vals_2d

Dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('my_example.tfrecords')
Dataset = Dataset.map(parse_tfrecord)
iterator = Dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(iterator.get_next()))
```

This will output the sequence of [5, 5] and the 2D numpy arrays. This blog post has a more in depth look at defining sequences with tfrecords https://dmolony3.github.io/Working%20with%20image%20sequences.html

Comment: Thank you very much! How can it be extended to a 2-D or higher dimensional input? One way may be to flatten it to a list and reshape it back when reading the file, which I can implement with keras model layers. But it needs dimension data at the destination. Is there a better way?

Comment: Also I couldn't open the link you shared (and your github site).

Comment: And what do you mean by 'context definition' and non sequential data? I couldn't get it. The context variable at the code output was also empty when I ran the code.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to process 2D data. Sequential data will consist of individual members of the sequence. Defining context allows us to provide information about the entire sequence. We only need to provide one context for the entire sequence and not for each member of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will play with it soon. BTW, could you please check again your github link you mentioned above? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: May I ask another question? I need to generate TFRecord file with sequences of 2D matrices, but each of them may have different number of rows because I am using them to train a LSTM network (for example one is of size 10x8, second is 12x8, etc.) I guess such a case can not be handled with context setting and I should just convert everything to strings and saving each matrix's shape also within each record to be able to convert it back. Is there any better solution?