# How to convert numpy.ndarray to _io.BytesIO

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray, object-detection-api

For making a train set for TensorFlow Object Detection model training. I need to generate a `tfrecord`. Here `tfrecord` consists of TensorFlow examples where each example is a `tf.train.Example` object. Following code shows how a TensorFlow example object is defined:

```
tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
```

But the problem is that I have to pass each image as `bytes_feature`. Here `encoded_jpg` is the image read from file and it is in `_io.BytesIO` format. It is not a big deal when I am reading image from disk. But as I am augmenting my image data set hence I am getting each of the augmented image as `numpy.ndarray`. So either I have to cast this `numpy.ndarray` image to `_io.BytesIO` or I have to save the image first such that I can read it in `_io.BytesIO` which makes no sense. So how I can easily convert the image to the desired format without requiring to save it to disk.

Comment: Can you use other libraries? You could convert the ndarray to a PIL and then save that as io.BytesIO

Comment: @Mntfr I don't want to save it. I want to pass the numpy.ndarray image directly to it (with casting to desired format).

Comment: Check this question [how to store numpy arrays as tfrecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861084/how-to-store-numpy-arrays-as-tfrecord)